# How to draw in UIViewController in landscape orientation on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, orientation, landscape

there are already some questions on this topic. Unfortunately none of them helped me in anyway. So here is the thing. I am working on an app atm and it has one **tabcontroller** with two tabs, which contain **multiple navigationcontroller** on top of each other. Now in one tab at the **top level navigation controller**, I want to **draw some graphics in landscape orientation.**

Unfortunately using the **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation** method returning YES does not help in anyway.

Now I was wondering whether I could just hide the statusBar and the navigationBar and then **draw my graphics so that it looks like it is landscape orientation**. But then I also would like to add some labels. I am quite sure I also could turn those around 90 degrees. But this is probably not the right approach here. And I want to submit my app someday...

So now I was hoping someone knows whats the best approach here and how to realize it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution somewhere else. The idea is to use the CGAffineTransform method. It allows you to transform the complete coordinate system of a uiview. The piece of code underneath rotatets it to landscape. Now when you draw, the drawing relates to the rotated coordinate systems and everything is drawn in landscape orientation.

```
CGAffineTransform transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, (90.0f*22.0f)/(180.0f*7.0f));
transform=CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 80, 80);
```

This does what I want. But anyway, if there are any other suggestions, please post them!